# How to give attribute to each <p> in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html

Now I'm making rich editor for my website using contenteditable div.
I use below code to create paragraph in contenteditable div.

```
document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p')
```

And now I want to give attribute,like 'name' 'id' 'class' , to each `<p>`. I searched the way to do this on the Internet But I couldn't find any solution.

Is there any way to do this?

**Postscript**

I made it by this way, I don't know if it's good way though.

```
<div id='body-text' class='body-text' contenteditable=true data-placeholder='Body Contents'></div>


var randomString = ['sa244', 'g345y', 'dg45t', 'gvr34', 'lutt7', '45btw', 'f3tqa']
var bodyContets = document.getElementById('body-text')
bodyContets.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp)

function onKeyUp(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode !== 13 || ( e.keyCode === 13 && (e.shiftKey === true || e.ctrlKey === true || e.altKey === true) )) {
        return false
    }
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
    for (var i = 0; i <= elements.length - 1; i++) {
        if(!elements[i].hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            elements[i].id = randomString[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code to assign attribute to any tag.

> document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].setAttribute("id", "idName");

in above code i am assigning **id=idName** to **p** tag.

hope it will help :)

Comment: I think @Hiro want to do that for all `p` & this will only work for first `p`

Comment: @AdnanUmer - Notice the 0 in the `("p")[0]` ? That indicates that it gets the first item of a collection of items. So, `var pElems = document.getElementsByTagName('p');` sets pElems equal to the array of all p elements on the page. pElems (like a string) has a length property - the number of items in it. You can access items 0 to length-1 with `pElems[index]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments here!! I made it by above code, I edited my question. If there is better way, please tell me

Answer (score 0):

by using jquery you can use the following code

> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> ```
> $("p").attr("attribute", "attributeValue");
> ```
>
> });

dont forgot to include the jquery library otherwise it will not execute properly.
(if you want the functionality on button click you can put the logic after **document.ready**)